# For loop over dygraph does not work in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, dygraphs

There is some strange behavior on `dygraph`.

When using a `for` loop for `dygraph` i get no result.

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)

for(i in 1:2){
  dygraph(lungDeaths[, i])
}
```

On the other hand when i use `lapply` i do get the expected result

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) dygraph(lungDeaths[, i]))
```

I actually want to use the `for` loop in `R Markdown` on my own data set and iterate over the different columns, but even when i use the `lapply` "workaround", it does not plot the `dygraphs`

**R Markdown code**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "dimitris_ps"
date: "28 May 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
lapply(1:2, function(i) dygraph(lungDeaths[, i]))
```
````

Whereas when i run it column by column it works

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "dimitris_ps"
date: "28 May 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
```

```{r}
dygraph(lungDeaths[, 1])
dygraph(lungDeaths[, 2])
```
````

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Session info**

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dygraphs_0.4.3 devtools_1.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.2.6 tools_3.2.0     yaml_2.1.13     rmarkdown_0.6.1 digest_0.6.8
```

Comment: `lapply` works in `markdown` for me. As to `for loop`, you can fix the problem (inefficient way) by using `show(dygraph(lungDeaths[, i]))`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately for me neither work. I will update my question with my `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I am using the same R version plus ‘0.4.3’ dygraphs version.

Comment: Same here. This is strange. I have tried it on 2 different machines but is still have the issue stated.

Comment: When I say `lapply`  and `show` option in `for loop` work, I mean I can only see in `viewer `not in  `html`. May be this has to do with `dynamic chart`. You can shoot  package maintainer an email on this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just wrap the list output from `lapply()` in `htmltools::tagList()`, e.g.

````
```{r}
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
res <- lapply(1:2, function(i) dygraph(lungDeaths[, i]))
htmltools::tagList(res)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, your the guru.

Comment: For shiny, use renderUI( htmltools::tagList(res) ) in the server and then htmlOutput() in the UI. (Rather than renderDygraph() and dygraphOutput()). Here's an example that helped me in Shiny: https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg246267.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with a loop, here's what worked for me.

```
p=list()
for (n in 1:3){
  p[[n]] <- plot_ly(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100)+n, mode = 'lines', type="scatter")
}
htmltools::tagList(p)
```

I.e. it doesn't matter if the list p is created in a loop or lapply, etc. as long as you call htmltools::tagList outside the loop.

Thanks to Yihui for helping me get there and for immense work developing and helping with these tools.

Comment: If you want to add some commentary about this answer - such as whether it is a duplicate answer - you could put it in the comments here under your answer.

Comment: Additional hint: instead of *renderDygraph* one has to use *renderUI*.