# How to print htmlwidgets to HTML result inside a function?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(DT)
xsx = function(){
  print(getOption("viewer"))
  print(datatable(data.frame(d =1)))
  1
}
xsx()
```
````

Inside xsx() function, DT widgets will not be rendered in HTML result. How can I get widgets print inside a function?

Comment: `htmltools::html_print()`?

Comment: The short answer is you cannot. A slightly longer answer: your best bet is to put everything in a list and use `htmltools::tagList()`; see this post for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30509866/559676 That may not be exactly what you want, but you cannot really mix arbitrary content with HTML widgets during printing.

Comment: @Yihui Thanks, `htmltools::tagList()` helps.