# Render a list of highcharts in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, highcharts, knitr, r-markdown

I generate a list of highcharts objects and tabs. Then I'd like to render it into an html page.

I can't figure out how to do it in a simple loop.

If i do it one by one it works, but not in a for.

Here is an example :

````
---
output: 
  html_document
---

``` {r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(highcharter)

out<-list(gr1=highcharts_demo(),gr2=highcharts_demo())

cat("

Column {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

")

cat("

###A1

"
)
out[[1]]

cat("

###A2

"
)
out[[2]]

for (i in c(1,2) )
{
  cat(paste0("

###","B",i,"

"
))
  out[[i]]
}
```
````

I compile it in RStudio with knitr.

And only the first two tabs have graphs, not the last two...

I tried to put explicit print or show, to add a \n in the loop. No luck.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567124/how-to-print-htmlwidgets-to-html-result-inside-a-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509866/for-loop-over-dygraph-does-not-work-in-r.  In summary:  you need to put the results in a "tagList".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment:  you can put each out[[i]] item in a tagList, and print it.  Your loop would become

```
for (i in c(1,2) )
{
  cat(paste0("

###","B",i,"

"
))
  print(htmltools::tagList(out[[i]]))
}
```

Comment: great works like a charm. I spent many hours research but couldn't link my problem to the references you mentionned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a problem though : if I remove the "direct" first prints (out[[1]] and out[[2]] lines) and leave only the loop with the tagList, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Probably the first ones trigger inclusion of something, and the tagList doesn't.  So do the first one manually, the rest in a loop.