# highcharter with blogdown casper-two theme

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, r-highcharter

I'm trying to render some graphs with `blogdown` (in `RMarkdown`).

The problem is that I'm not able to render `highcharter` graphs with [`casper-two`](https://github.com/eueung/hugo-casper-two) theme.
I'v tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509866/for-loop-over-dygraph-does-not-work-in-r) approach and nothing happens.

After select `New Post` in RStudio addin I do this:

````
```{r}
library(highcharter)

mtcars <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars)

hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(wt, mpg, color = hp))
```
````

And this is what I get:

[image]

---

When I execute the same code above (except by the `R` . Rmd chunk part) I can visualize the graph perfectly:

[image]

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the output that you get looks like is the preview of your post on the home page. I can see that when you do go to the post itself, the code retains its pretty output but it's not loading the plot. Some other js/css might be messing with it.

A way to fix this is to wrap the plot in iframe like this:

````r
```{r}
library(highcharter)
library(widgetframe)
mtcars <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars)

frameWidget(hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(wt, mpg, color = hp)))
```
````

To fix the preview section, in your post yaml you can add

```html
description: "Your description"
```

so that the preview doesn't look so ugly. Another way is to modify the layout of the preview. This is tricky so I would not recommend it.

Comment: It wroked perfectly! Thank you!