# dygraph in R multiple plots at once

Tags: r, plot, time-series, dygraphs

I want to plot multiple plots at once using dygraph (they do not have to be synchronized in the first step)

Base R-example:

```
temperature <- ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1980, 1),
       data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 
       25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6))
rainfall <- ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1980, 1),
       data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
       135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4))

par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(temperature)
plot(rainfall)
```

With dygraph this approach does not work

```
require(dygraphs)
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
dygraph(temperature)
dygraph(rainfall)
```

I know there's the possibility to display second axis etc. But maybe someone knows an answer to displaying both plots at once

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To plot multiple *dygraphs* in the same RStudio window you must first create a list of *dygraphs* objects, and then render the *dygraphs* list using package *htmltools*.  Yihui Xie from RStudio provided the answer here:
[Yihui Xie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509866/for-loop-over-dygraph-does-not-work-in-r/35235069#35235069) (but without grouping).
I answered a similar question here:  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267286/r-how-to-plot-dygraphs-in-multiple-panels/46730868#46730868).

Here is working `R` code that produces grouped (synchronized) *dygraphs* plots:

```
# create the time series
temperature <- ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1980, 1),
              data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 
                       25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6))
rainfall <- ts(frequency = 12, start = c(1980, 1),
           data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
                    135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4))

# create a list of dygraphs objects
library(dygraphs)
library(htmltools)
plotobj <- list(
  dygraphs::dygraph(temperature, group="temp_rain", main="temperature"),
  dygraphs::dygraph(rainfall, group="temp_rain", main="rainfall")
)  # end list

# render the dygraphs objects using htmltools
htmltools::browsable(htmltools::tagList(plotobj))
```

The above `R` code produces the following grouped (synchronized) *dygraphs* plots:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to make these graphs full screen?

Comment: By default dygraphs plots in the small RStudio plot window.  You can pop it out by clicking the *Zoom* button.  I don't know of a programmatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to export to a external document such as html

See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/