# Dygraph in R, Synching the hoover

Tags: r, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

It's a follow up to this questions: [dygraph in R multiple plots at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502506/dygraph-in-r-multiple-plots-at-once)

Is it possible to synchronize these two plots in a way that the pointer (hoover) on one, shows the value in the other graph for the same time point?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to look the Shiny Apps : https://shiny.rstudio.com/

You might find your answer there !