# r - how to plot dygraphs in multiple panels

Tags: css, r, dygraphs

I was trying to plot dynamic graph in different panels as it could be done on the website using `group` such as [image]

but it should be dynamic using dygraphs. An example code here:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
data(edhec)
R = edhec[, 1:4]
dygraph(R)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Create multiple charts, using the `synchronization` feature [here](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-synchronization.html)

To view it as one document, you will need to `knit` an HTML page. Look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094507/how-to-save-interactive-charts-from-dygraph) answer for details.

Your final result would be like [this](http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! I've seen these before but what I expect  is to display it in the plotting window of R/RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

To plot multiple *dygraphs* in the same RStudio window you must first create a list of *dygraphs* objects, and then render the *dygraphs* list using package *htmltools*.  Yihui Xie from RStudio provided the answer here: 
[Yihui Xie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509866/for-loop-over-dygraph-does-not-work-in-r/35235069#35235069) (but without grouping).

Here is working `R` code that produces grouped *dygraphs* candlestick plots:

```
# load packages
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
library(htmltools)

# download time series into an environment
sym_bols <- c("VTI", "EEM")
data_env <- new.env()
quantmod::getSymbols(sym_bols, from="2017-01-01", env=data_env)

# create a list of dygraphs objects in a loop
dy_graph <- eapply(data_env, function(x_ts) {
  dygraphs::dygraph(x_ts[, 1:4], group="etfs",
    main=paste("Plot of:", substring(colnames(x_ts)[1], 1, 3)),
      width=600, height=400) %>% dygraphs::dyCandlestick()
})  # end eapply

# render the dygraphs objects using htmltools
htmltools::browsable(htmltools::tagList(dy_graph))

# perform same plotting as above using pipes syntax
# create a list of dygraphs objects in a loop
eapply(data_env, function(x_ts) {
  dygraphs::dygraph(x_ts[, 1:4], group="etfs",
    main=paste("Plot of:", substring(colnames(x_ts)[1], 1, 3)),
      width=600, height=400) %>% dygraphs::dyCandlestick()
}) %>% # end eapply
# render the dygraphs objects using htmltools
  htmltools::tagList() %>% htmltools::browsable()
```

The above `R` code produces the following grouped *dygraphs* candlestick plots:

[image]